# How to incorporate DRAG feature in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, matplotlib

I want to incorporate DRAG feature in program where in I can drag (hand cursor) the canvas which is placed on a panel. DRAG feature will help me see a full picture if the image is out of bound on the axis or if the image is zoomed in.

Currently I am using wxmpl library which is a integration of matplotlib and wxPython. but it seems like this library does not have DRAG feature.

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Thanks
Damodar

Answer (score 0):

wxmpl might be a bit outdated (it hasn't been updated in over a year and before that it went 2 years).  The current releases of matplotlib provide excellent WX support.  In fact the feature you want is already included with the NavigationToolbar and the FigureCanvasWxAgg included in the base matplotlib.  Take a look at this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html).  I believe you are describing the "Pan" control (it's the arrows in all 4 directions icon).